# UPDATE new table JOIN two other tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I am going nuts trying to figure this out....please help :(
I have three tables and I am updating a table from the data of two other tables.

Update table: set_colors
columns: setcolors_id (primary), art_id(int), baseimage_id(int), color_id(int)

Two tables I am getting information from

Table name: art
columns: id(primary), artname(varchar), series_code(varchar)

table name: baseimage
columns: id(primary), base_folder(varchar), graphic, image_type(varchar), layer(int)
example data:

The **series_code** from the art table and the **base_folder** from the **baseimage** table have identical values but where the art table can have hundreds of duplicate series codes and baseimage may only have 5 max if the same base_folder name but has different layers.

example data:

[image: Art Table]
[image: baseimage]

I want to UPDATE the set_colors table with the art table [id], baseimage [id], and where the baseimage = "B", so what it needs to do is iterate through the art table "layer" column-- the color_id will be updated by another sql query so some rows may be an int or NULL

So the result should look something like this:

[image: Result Set Colors table]

what I came up with is this but it does not work, No error message. it just does not populate the table. What am I missing??

```
$result_array = mysql_query("
 UPDATE set_colors 
 JOIN art 
 JOIN baseimage 
 ON  art.series_code = baseimage.base_folder
 SET set_colors.school_art_id = art.id, 
set_colors.baseimage_id = baseimage.id, 
set_colors.baseimage_layer = baseimage.layer 
WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B'"   
);
 return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
```

Comment: Do you really want to UPDATE existing rows or are you actually trying to INSERT new rows?

Comment: Well now THAT is a good point! I guess it would be in INSERT being that it would not exist yet... doh. If that is the case is the query the same except instead of UPDATE, it should read INSERT? Actually I just tried it and it did not work, so I am still doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think your insert statement should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO set_colors
    (art_id, baseimage_id)
    SELECT a.id, b.id
        FROM baseimage b
            INNER JOIN art a
                ON b.base_folder = a.series_code
        WHERE b.image_type = 'B'
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!! Being new at this can really suck at times, what is clearly obvious can be completely elusive for someone who is relatively new. Thanks again, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking over the MySQL UPDATE documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).  I believe your update needs to be restructured based upon MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you say "populate the table", are you expecting this query to insert new rows?  An update query will not create new rows, only update rows that already exist in the table.

Second, it looks like you are expecting `mysql_query` to return an array.  This function only returns `true` or `false` when executing insert or update queries depending if the query executed correctly.